# Need Technology Recommendation: Web-based Database Manager

Tags: javascript, html, database-schema

I'd like to build a proof-of-concept web-based database manager (such as the desktop version in the screenshot below) that has the following features.

The schema will be provided initially through a flat file.

It seems like HTML5 might be an option. What about non-HTML? What about processing.js? Are there any libraries I could/should take advantage? Is there already a service I can tap into?

Any opinions or advice would be appreciated!

**Edit**
Primary goal of the project is the build a protoype of the UI.

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is the first webapp you've ever done huh? Do you have a team or is this a solo project? Are you going to be doing a UML editor like that?

Comment: No, it's not the first. And I'm not looking to build a completely functional demo - just a protoype of the UI. I just wanted to leave it high-level to get the most amount of feedback.

Comment: I started something like this in order to learn how to do it. It's a little glitchy but works: http://preview.moveable.com/jm/jameslab/ajaxio/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to use http://raphaeljs.com for the project. This SVG library supports older browsers and given this application is highly interactive with the user, it makes sense for me in this project to use SVG over Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

For the events that you will need to control everything, I would suggest using [jQuery](http://jquery.com). It can cut you javascript in half. Canvas/SVG would be easy enough to use to create the diagram above (could even pull it off in straight html using some creative css and a judicious application of div's). I've never used flash but I also don't see anything in your image here that couldn't be done in Canvas/SVG. If you do go with Canvas you will want to look into using a lib called [ex_canva](http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/)s which will make it all work fairly nicely on IE (my company has some canvas items that work in IE6 using ex_canvas). Also you will want to look at [css-sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites) (in case you haven't heard of them before) as they can aid in the load performance of your page.

Comment: I agree, jQuery is really the best, it solves all kinds of browser problems and is good, as well.